# Specifying timeout when reading URL image with MATLAB imread function

Tags: matlab, timeout

The MATLAB imread function provides the ability to read an image from a URL. This generally works OK, but occasionally I encounter an image that takes a very long time to respond.

For instance, at the time of posting the following URL appears to just be stuck in a 'connecting...' state for over 5 minutes before finally succeeding.

http://www.hollywoodheadache.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/tom-and-julia.jpg

Is there any way I can set a timeout within MATLAB?

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention that once it hangs like this my only recourse - other than waiting for an indeterminate time period - is to kill the MATLAB process (well I suppose killing my net connection would also work) as Ctrl-C interrupt does not work. This makes working with a large dataset of URLs very irritating.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to interrupt `imread` with a timer object. Besides, I suspect about its possibility. But I may recommend you to check whether you can access to the file first, and then, you get the file. I have written the following function to check the file and internet status:

```
function flag = does_url_exist(urlName) 
    url =java.net.URL(urlName);
    try
        link = openStream(url); 
        parse = java.io.InputStreamReader(link); 
        snip = java.io.BufferedReader(parse); 
        if ~isempty(snip) 
            flag = 1; 
        else 
            flag = 0;
        end 
    catch exception
        flag = 0;
    end
end
```

Then it is as follows:

```
fname = 'http://www.hollywoodheadache.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/tom-and-julia.jpg';
if(does_url_exist(fname))
    img = imread(fname);
end
```

Note that for internet connection checking, I took the initial code from [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.matlab/browse_thread/thread/e82171ae5f1cc095?pli=1). Also note that if you are sure that the file exists, it is not efficient to check it again since it increases the running time.

Comment: My feeling is that the issue only arises when a connection is successfully established, but the image retrieval is extremely slow. imread seems to fail quickly for definitely non-existent images. It only happens rarely and inconsistently so it's hard to test, but I will give this a try anyway. In any case, it's opened my eyes to the fact MATLAB has some java capabilities, which gives me another direction to explore.

Comment: Yes, you can try the Java way if you're good at Java. Unfortunately, I'm not so.